# Replace negative numbers, NaN and 0s with mean of next and previous positive number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace, time-series

I want to replace negative numbers, NaNs and 0s with mean of next and previous positive number of same column.

Original dataframe

```
    a   c
0   1   1
1   2   2
2   0   5
3   -3  NaN
4   -1  5
5   3   3
```

Expected output dataframe is

```
    a    c
0   1     1
1   2     2
2   2.5   5    #In Col a --> Mean of 2 and 3 is 2.5 hence 0 replaced by 2.5
3   2.75  5  #In Col a --> Mean of 2.5 and 3 is 2.75 hence negative no. replaced by 2.75
4   2.875 5    #In Col a --> Mean of 2.75 and 3 is 2.875 hence negative no. replaced by 2.875
5   3     3
```

I tried another strategy to deal with negative no. Nan and 0 is replacing it with mean of previous 3 values

```
m = df['a'] < 1
new = (df.loc[~m, 'a'].astype(float)
         .rolling(2, min_periods=1).mean()
         .reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))

df['a'].mask(m, new)
```

which results in

```
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    1.5
3    1.5
4    1.5
5    2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

However I'm struggling to implement the new strategy (asked).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would imagine it was downvoted because you don't show what you've tried and failed with. It's nice to show that you've given the problem a good amount of thought yourself before requesting that other people think about your problem too

Comment: Thanks @CallumDA! I have implemented another strategy added in the question however in order to improve the accuracy of the model I need a help to implement this second strategy.

Comment: Much better. It now looks like a *good* question. I've upvoted accordingly

Answer (score 3):

I edited my answer to better address your question. Note however, that the mean of 5 and 5 is 5, and not 2.5 as you wrote in yout expected result.

This new answer is based on hpchavaz's answer below.

```
# Replace 0 and negative values with NaN
df = df.mask(df<=0)

# Compute rank of consecutive NaN values
rank = df.isnull().astype('int')
rank = rank.cumsum() - rank.cumsum().where(rank==0).ffill().fillna(0)
print(rank)

     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0
3  2.0  1.0
4  3.0  0.0
5  0.0  0.0

# Compute first and last non null value before NaN range
first = df.ffill()
last = df.bfill()

# Finally, compute final df
df = last - (last-first)/2**(rank)
print(df)

       a    b
0  1.000  1.0
1  2.000  2.0
2  2.500  5.0
3  2.750  5.0
4  2.875  5.0
5  3.000  3.0
```

### Previous answer

You can call `mask` to replace null and negative values with NaN, then `interpolate`

Not really sure why you expect the NaN in your second column to be replaced with 2.5 instead of 5 though...

```
>>> df.mask(df<=0).interpolate()
      a    b
0  1.00  1.0
1  2.00  2.0
2  2.25  5.0
3  2.50  5.0
4  2.75  5.0
5  3.00  3.0
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output as the question does not ask for interpolation .

Comment: You're right, however since they are inconsistencies between the expected result and what the OP say they want, I kinda assumed that interpolation could fit their need

Comment: I don't understand why you keep insisting that the mean of 5 and 5 is 2.5. It just isn't. Maybe you need to have this 2.5 value in your output dataframe, but is is NOT the mean. (5+5)/2 = 5

Comment: @YoannQuenachdeQuivillic You are right!  Thanks!

Comment: @YoannQuenachdeQuivillic I have upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Heavily edited version

Define a function to return a corrected version of a series

- build a mask : m
- modify the serie setting by NaN for values to be replaced
- build a series from mask with 0: 1: tocorrect
- build a series of the ranks for each sequence to be corrected : sequence_ranks
- build lower and upper values series using ffill and bfill : 'lower_bound_values' and 'upper_bound_values '
- calculate the result using 'lower_bound_values ' 'upper_bound_values

```
def correct_series_values(ser):
    m = (ser<=0) | ser.isna()
    ser[m] = np.nan
    tocorrect = m.astype('int')
    sequence_ranks = tocorrect.cumsum() - tocorrect.cumsum().where(tocorrect==0).ffill().fillna(0)
    lower_bound_values, upper_bound_values = ser.ffill(), ser.bfill()
    ser[m] = (lower_bound_values[m] - upper_bound_values[m]) / 2**(sequence_ranks[m]) + upper_bound_values[m]
    return ser

df['a'] = correct_series_values(df['a'])
df['c'] = correct_series_values(df['c'])
```

DF:

```
        a     c
0   1.000   1.0
1   2.000   2.0
2   2.500   5.0
3   2.750   5.0
4   2.875   5.0
5   3.000   3.0
```

Comment: @Suhas_Pote updated.

Comment: @Suhas_Pote : As Yohann stated, the mean of 5 and 5 is 5. You may need an other correction, and you should in this cas modify the function. But I am eager to see how that would be consistent with the  corrected valus for column 'a'.

Comment: You are right! Thanks :)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer.